# Declaratively set permissions on Postgres table via Django Model?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

We have two different groups working on the same Django database:

1. The web team
2. A team of data scientists

We'd like to make it easy for the data scientists to read/write to a subset of a tables using Django models but without giving them write/delete access to the rest of the tables.

Our current thought is that we'd like to lock down the tables in the data layer (Postgres) with GRANT and REVOKE style SQL statements, but we'd like to manage those permissions in the models.

We'd have two ROLES:

1. `data_scientists_rw`
2. `web_team_admin`

Instead of manually writing GRANT and REVOKE permissions in each migration, we'd like to have a decorator or a Meta class variable on a model so that when we `makemigrations`, it will automatically generate the correct SQL.

```
# data_scientists/models.py (pseudocode)
class DataScientistModel(models.Model):
    ...
    my_special_number = models.FloatField()
    ...
    class Meta:
        data_science_team_editable = True
```

Make the migration:

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations
```

Auto-generated model (pseudocode):

```
# migrations/0008_new_data_scientist_model.py
...
if data_science_team_editable:
    RunSQL('GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON {tablename} TO data_scientists_rw;')
...
```

Questions:

1. Does this approach seem sensible?
2. How I do hook into `makemigrations` so that I can auto-generate the RunSQL code?